# Adding values into particular rows by column using sql query

Tags: sql

I added one new column in my table which is country. Now I want to add countries to particular rows like for rows whose productID is 104, 106, 107. What I have used query is giving error. Please help!

```
update products
    set country in ("usa","uk","India")
    where productID in ("104","106", "107");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the logic you want:

```
update products
    set country = (case when productID = 104 then 'usa'
                        when productID = 106 then 'uk'
                        when productID = 107 then 'india'
                   end)
    where productID in (104, 106, 107);
```

Note:  do not use `"` for constants.  Use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use delimiters for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE`:

```
update products
set country =  
      CASE product_id  WHEN 104 THEN 'usa' when 106 THEN 'uk' WHEN 107 THEN 'india' END
where productID in ('104','106', '107');
```